# Replace characters in user part of email address

Tags: sed, awk, regular-expression

I have a list that looks like this:

```
user-name@domain.example
user.name@domain.example
user_name@domain.example
...
```

I would like to replace any occurence of a dot in the username part. So that:

```
user.name@domain.example
```

becomes:

```
user^name@domain.example
```

I tried it with sed but couldnt get a Regex together to only apply the change to the username part. Do you have an idea for a pattern to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's more than one dot, but only one dot after the @ sign (which would be usual), you can just change all dots and change the last one back:

```
sed 'y/./^/;s/\(@.*\)\^/\1./'
```

If there's potentially more than one dot both before and after the @ sign, you can do it recursively with a short loop:

```
sed ':top;s/\.\(.*@\)/^\1/;ttop'
```

This works in GNU sed; BSD sed requires a newline after a label:

```
sed ':top 
s/\.\(.*@\)/^\1/;ttop'
```

**EDIT:** To handle all cases in either GNU sed or BSD sed in a single line command:

```
sed 'h;s/@.*//;y/./^/;G;s/\n.*@/@/'
```

`h` copies current line (called the "pattern space") to the hold space; the `s` command deletes the `@` and everything after it; `y` works like the shell command `tr` and in this case translates all dots to carets; `G` appends a newline and the hold space contents to the pattern space; then the last `s` command deletes from the newline up to the `@` and puts back the `@`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I wanted since it might be, that the domain part contains more dots

Answer (score 4):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F"@" '{gsub("\.","^",$1)}OFS="@"' file
```

- `-F"@"` delimits the input with `@`.
- `gsub()` replaces all dots with `^` in the first field `$1` (the name part before the `@`).
- `OFS` sets the output field separator.

Comment: Interesting trick with the OFS="@"...  I couldn't figure out how that worked at first!  I would tend to write it as: `awk -F"@" -v OFS="@" '{gsub("\.","^",$1);print}' file`

Comment: @Brian This is just a shortcut. Inside the brackets `{}` awk changes something and then we need a true condition that awk prints the line. You could also write `{}1` where 1 is the true condition, but I anyway have to set the `OFS` variable so I used that as true condition.

Comment: Interesting...I always set OFS and FS either on the command line or in a BEGIN block; I feel it's cleaner.  There seems to be a mistake with the `"\."` pattern; on my machine it replaces ALL chars in $1.  Seems you need either `"\\."` or `/\./`.  Adding one to the return value of gsub is a sufficient "true" test: `awk -F'@' -v OFS='@' 'gsub(/\./,"^",$1) + 1'`

Comment: @Wildcard You're using `gawk`. This answer was written using `mawk`. With `gawk`, you have to add slashes. And that statement `OFS="@"`. That was my inner code golfer =) It's less clear, but more elegant...

Answer (score 3):

If you only have a single dot, you can use

```
sed 's/\.\(.*\)@/^\1@/'
```

which matches the dot, then captures the rest until the `@`, and replaces it
by `^`, the capture, and `@`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it with `sed`.

```
sed ':start s/^\([^@]*\)\./\1^/; t start;' "$@"
```

`:start` is a *label* to branch to.

`^\([^@]*\)\.`  is a *regular expression* (aka *regex*), that matches, at the beginning of line, 0 or more of any character except the at-sign, followed by a dot.
The `\(` and `\)` signify a *back reference* which means anything which matches the enclosed pattern can be referenced in the replacement side with `\1`.

`\1^` is the *replacement*. `\1` is replaced by whatever matched `\([^@]*\)` in the regular expression. The circumflex (^) will replace the dot which notice was excluded from the back reference.

`t` is a sed *test* which will branch to the given label if the previous subsitution was successful.  This enables the script to replace more than one dot in the email address.

Comment: +1 for good explanation.  This wasn't here when I started writing my answer.  :)  See note in my answer about labels and newlines in BSD `sed`, though.  (Mac OS X uses BSD sed.)

Answer (score 0):

A system which has sed and awk will also often have perl, and if you're open to a perl solution, try

```
perl -ne '($user, $domain) = split "@"; $user =~ s/\./^/g; print "$user\@$domain"'
```

As long as your email addresses are fairly normal and each line contains one address (and nothing else), this works in the straightforward way: split the address on `@`, replace all periods in the first part with carets, and print out the two parts together as an email address.

You could also get tricky and do this:

```
perl -pe 's/\.(?=.*@)/^/g'
```

which uses a regex to replace any period which comes before an `@` symbol with a caret. It relies on a lookahead assertion, a feature which is not implemented in sed's or awk's regular expression flavors, as far as I know. I'd guess this may be slower for long lists, but run your own tests and see if it matters.